# System.Web.OData not defined when installing Microsoft.AspNet.Odata

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, odata

I am trying to follow this Microsoft tutorial with no luck. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint . I created the web api project on visual studio 2017, and runned "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Odata" on Package Manager Console, but I still get System.Web.OData namespace undefined ("The type or namespace Odata does not exist on 'System.Web'"). Any clue why is this happening?. The version of Odata installed is 7.0.1. Should I get another version?

Answer (score 4):

See https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/315:

> With Microsoft.AspNet.OData v7.0, namespaces were changed from `System.Web.OData` to `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`.

Answer (score 0):

I found `Microsoft.AspNet.OData 7.0.0` or above (even though `7.0.1` or `7.1.0`) doesn't contain `System.Web.Odata`.
You can install `Microsoft.AspNet.OData 6.1.0` then S`ystem.Web.Odata` will be auto-added under reference.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.OData -Version 6.1.0
```